# AngularJS Chart for Races

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, charts

I have my file JSON like this and with this time format, there are time of laps:

```
[{"time":"00:05:52.92"},{"time":"00:06:22.26"},{"time":"00:06:22.26"},{"time":"00:02:22.26"},{"time":"00:07:22.26"},{"time":"00:06:22.26"},{"time":"00:00:22.26"},{"time":"00:01:22.26"},{"time":"00:04:22.26"}]
```

With angularjs, I don't know what kind of chart use, and which dependecies use for this, can you give me some advices please. I can use my json like this or I have to trasform in seconds? if I must trasform in what? just seconds?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking unfortunately

Comment: if u wanna use this data format u can just read your Json via ng-repeat and create <tr> like this if u want

Comment: <tr>? I can use tr for charts? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

with this function I solved my problems:

```
function (secs){   
    var divisor_for_minutes = secs.value % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
    return minutes + ":" + divisor_for_seconds.toFixed(2);
    }
```